# Android-Writing to a file results in random characters

Tags: java, android, null

Argargarg.

I am trying to get information from a user input, then to write it to a system file. I get the input, and I call getBytes on it. It logs to the file something along the lines of "null" and random numbers after that. I tried getting it to a string, no luck there, it was a random chain of symbols
Here is the specific code:

```
        TextView note_input=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.note_input);
    FileOutputStream fos=null;
    String newNote=note_input.getText().toString();
    Log.w("Debug",newNote);
    try {
        fos=openFileOutput("currentNote",Context.MODE_APPEND);
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        //IT_SHOUD_NOT_EXIST
    }
    try {
        Log.w("Debug",newNote.getBytes().toString());
        fos.write(newNote.getBytes());
        fos.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

I appreciate any help!

Comment: Does your log write proper output and you just have problems with your file?

Comment: It doesn't. The problem is with the function getBytes.(I think)

Comment: Is there a reason you're using an OutputStream (byte-based) rather than a Writer (character-based) for your output file?

Comment: Also, a hex dump of the output file would help us see what's getting written. Plus, tell us what the string was.

Answer (score 0):

String.getBytes returns array of bytes, and when you try to do toString() you are actually writing it's pointer to string. You already have String change this line

```
Log.w("Debug",newNote.getBytes().toString());
```

into

```
Log.w("Debug",newNote);
```

and you will have proper Log output, and File should be written properly already.

Hope this helps and enjoy your work

Comment: I did that in an attempt to check out what happened. The result that gets written in the file is also wrong

Answer (score 0):

Just a shot in the dark, but I notice you're calling getBytes() without specifying the character encoding. Unless your output file is the same character encoding as the system default encoding, you could easily get gibberish on the output.